# Объясните почему тут постоянно итерируется 0 индекс?

Tags: python

```
def modify_list (l):
    
    for x in l[:]:
        
        if x % 2 == 0:
            
            l.append(x//2)
    
    l.remove(x)

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

modify_list (l)
```

Объясните почему тут постоянно итерируется 0 индекс?

Comment: Найдите информацию о том что такое отладчик и сделайте отладку своего кода

Comment: вы не можете изменять массив, элементы которого перебираются в цикле, вам надо создать новый массив, делать изменения в нем, и потом приравнять изначальный массив к новому. А сейчас у вас полная петрушка, и код работает логически неправильно, и цикл работает дольше чем надо

Answer (score 1):

`if x % 2 == 0:`

Это не нулевой индекс. `%` - означает операцию нахождения остатка

`% 2` - остаток от деления на 2

Соответственно `if x % 2 == 0:` читается так `если остаток от деления на 2 равен нулю, то`